# Why is my dictionary value changing without me telling it to, and how do I stop it?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

This is my sample code:

```
dict1 = {'a': 5, 'b': 6, 'c': 7}
dict2 = dict1
for i in dict1:
    dict1[i] += 5
print dict1
print dict2
```

Output looks like this:

```
{'a': 10, 'c': 12, 'b': 11}
{'a': 10, 'c': 12, 'b': 11}
```

Why is dict2 changing without me telling it to?

Python 2.7.10 on GCC 4.8.2 Linux.

Also tried on 2.7.12 on GCC 5.4.0, same result.

Comment: dict2 is not a dictionary. It's a reference to the dictionary. It points to the same dictionary as dict1.

Comment: You will need to **copy** your dictionary to variable `dict2` otherwise you are just referencing the same spot in memory!

Comment: You only have *one dictionary*.

Comment: In Python the `=` works a bit different to many other programming languages: it will create a reference to the object on the right side and push that reference as a name into a namespace. No direct assignment is done.

Answer (score 0):

When you write `dict2 = dict1`, you are not creating the copy of `dict1`, you just set `dict2` as a pointer to the `dict1` dictionary. So if you change `dict1`, `dict2` will be changed too because it looks at the same dictionary in memory. If you want to copy `dict1` to `dict2`, you should use [deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html?highlight=deepcopy#copy.deepcopy) function from the `copy` module from the Python standard library.